# Integrated wifi does not work

Tags: wifi

I bought the Raspberry Pi 3 around a year ago and maybe 6 months ago I used retropie on it and fiddled with some internet settings. A week later I changed the OS and the integrated wlan0 never worked again, (ethernet works fine)

Did I accidently switch the wifi off somehow? I checked /boot/config.txt and nothing is disabled there, nothing evident in /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf either.

I'm currently trying to use raspbian, the current release main branch, March 2018. When I do sudo iwlist wlan0 scan it comes up as ''interface doesnt support scanning''. When I do ifconfig-a only eth0 and lo come up too.

What are the most common causes of these problems? I looked around on a slimdevices thread but it didn't help very much. Sorry if this is poorly written, Im trying my best.

Comment: You changed OS but have not told us what OS you are now using. You have not given us your current WiFi settings. "Did I accidentally switch the WiFi off somehow" How do you expect us to answer that ...guess?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm currently trying to use raspbian, the current release main branch, March 2018. When I do sudo iwlist wlan0 scan it comes up as ''interface doesnt support scanning''. When I do ifconfig-a only eth0 and lo come up too.

Comment: @DQN I'm having a similar problem.  I'm marking your question as a favorite so that I can keep up with the progress.  I suggest that you consider adding the description of your OS and what you have already tried to your question.  This will make it easier for the other users to follow your issue.  I have the **Raspberry PI 3** also running the **Raspbian** OS.  I made some changes in an attempt to configure it as a **Hotspot** .  Now my Wifi has stopped working on that install.  The Wifi works on a fresh install... (cont)

Comment: ..(cont)  I want to try the **Hotspot** again.  But trying to learn how to undo changes if the Wifi stops working again.  If I figure it out, I'll provide the resolution here.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself - not in comments. Thanks.